# Detecting last line with dbms_output.put_line

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-output

I'm curious on how to code this process.  I am using collection objects to pull information from a table.  Then I am using `dbms_output.put_line` to display the values that I collected.

I want to append a line to the last line of my output. For example:

table A

```
col1 col2  
1     3  
2     4
```

I pull the values and use `dbms_output.put_line` to display those items.

It would display:

```
1,3  
2,4
```

Is there a way to append "This is the last line" to the last line collected/displayed to show...

```
1,3  
2,4 This is the last line
```

I tried to add another `dbms_output.put_line` after my loop during the collection process, but it just treats it as 2 lines.

```
1,3  
2,4  
This is the last line.
```

Comment: Post the code you are currently using.  It will depend, among other things, on the type of collection you are using, whether it is sparse or dense, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to insert a new line **before** each line of text - except the first line.

```
create table taba(
 col1 number,
 col2 number
);
insert into taba values (1,2);
insert into taba values (3,4);
commit;

declare
  type tab_t is table of taba%rowtype;
  tab tab_t;
  cursor c is select * from taba;
  first_row boolean;
begin
  open c;
  fetch c bulk collect into tab;
  close c;

  first_row := true;
  for x in 1..tab.count loop
     if not first_row then
        dbms_output.put_line('');
     end if;
     first_row := false;
     dbms_output.put( tab( x ).col1 || ',' || tab( x ).col2 );
  end loop;
  if not first_row then
     dbms_output.put_line('   This is the last line');
  else
     dbms_output.put_line('The table is empty');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Results:

```
1,2
3,4   This is the last line
```

Comment: I'd use `dbms_output.new_line` rather than `dbms_output.put_line('')`, but the effect is the same.